# Adding and Removing Home Tabs

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

When I started using Firefox, it automatically began opening the 7 or 8 tabs that were automatically opening when I used Internet Explorer.

I want to remove one of those tabs and identify another to automatically appear when I start Firefox.  How?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what version of Firefox you are on, but it's pretty standard across the versions.

1. Click the Firefox Menu
2. Click "Options" (preferences probably on mac)
3. In the main window that pops up, you have your Set Homepage box.  Enter the URLs in there separated by the "pipe" character >> | <<  It's generally above the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Example: `http://www.google.com|http://superuser.com|http://blog.whydoireadthis.com`

[image: step]
[image: step1b]

(Please excuse the blinking line in "https", that isn't part of getting your urls)